# How to find max thread active for scatter-gather in mule

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-component, mule-esb

I am using mule version **3.9**.
My application uses **HTTP listener component** as an message source and uses scatter gather to collect data from database.
During performance testing, "Threadpoolexecutor did not accept within 30000 MILLISECONDS (java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException)" is thrown. I think this is due to non-availability of enough threads for scatter gather component.

As per mule doc, maxThreadsActive for Scatter-Gather is the number of routes in a Scatter-Gather * maxThreadsActive for flow. Now, how to find maxThreadsActive for flow? No processing strategy is defined for flow. pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [default threading profile documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/tuning-performance#default-threading-profile):

> maxThreadsActive  The maximum number of threads to use.
>
> ```
> Type: integer
> Required: no
> Default: 16
> ```

Having said that I recommend that instead of increasing the number of threads it is better to analyze a thread dump to understand what are the existing threads doing when they are all busy. Probably you have some operation that is taking more time than expected (the database query?). Increasing the number of threads should be evaluated with performance test to understand the improvement and cost. Threads are not free, they use memory and CPU.

Comment: Thanks aled. As per mule Doc, "The default threading profile, used by components and by endpoints for dispatching and receiving if no more specific configuration is given."

I have configured, default threading profile, dispatcher threading profile and receiver threading profile. 
so out of these three, maxthreadsactive configured for  default threading profile will be the max number of thread for flow. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's a different question. I strongly don't recommend to change the default configuration as it affects other flows/components too. Instead use a specific configuration for the affected flow.

Comment: ok aled. I get that. My question is different. For example, say if I have maxthreadsactive as 32 in default threading profile and the mentioned scatter-gather has 3 routes. Then I have to configure 96 (32 * 3) as maxthreadsactive value for scatter-gather threading profile. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if the calculation is the correct one. Note that the original question was how to find the default maxThreadsActive. I believe that was answered. Now you have a new question which seems to be about what is the 'right' value for a specific scenario. For me it is a separate question that I don't think has a straightforward answer.